# INSERT INTO temp table not working in stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

This script works fine when running on dbeaver, I can work with the new created temp table:

```
SELECT someField
INTO TEMP tmp_TableZZ 
FROM "_fdw_xxx".myTable;
```

But when inside a stored procedure, I got this error message:

> ```
> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: "temp" is not a known variable
> ```

Same code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure PopulateSomething() 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
    DECLARE v_ReportDte date;
begin

--some code omitted

    SELECT someField
    INTO TEMP tmp_TableZZ 
    FROM "_fdw_xxx".myTable;

--some code omitted

end; $procedure$
;
```

Using `TEMPORARY` instead of `TEMP` got the same result.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why the standard compliant `create table new_table as select ...` is recommended over `select ... into new_table ..`

Comment: Get rid of the MixedCase identfiers (or quote them)

Answer (score 1):

well, I find out that SELECT INTO in SQL is different from SELECT INTO in pgsql.
The former accepts TEMP as the parameter, the latter expects a variable to store some value.